# Assets I imported won't show in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to import the RPG game assets from devassets.com, but after I run the Unity Package File, It can't be seen ANYWHERE. It's not in the Package Manager, or the project folder. I'm not sure if it's something wrong on my computer, but I need help.

I reset the editor, but still, the same error happened. I also redownload it, but it still showed the same result. Usally, I see the asset I imported on the Project folder, but for this one nothing happened. The Unity Package File did run, and did everything it needed to, but it did not show.I'm not sure if this is related to this issue, but the console kept saying: LMDB_Transaction::Run - LMDB error = 1006 AND [PackageManager] Could not create file at: D:/Files/Projects/Unity Projects/RPG/Packages/manifest.json.

Oh, and by the way (if this is helpful), I installed Unity on my hard drive, but I selected my USB drive when it asked me the location to download that project.
[Picture:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sy0tI.png)

Comment: what is D? is it covered by onedrive, googledrive, icloud, shared drive?

Comment: Try moving the project to your hard drive. There might be some read/write issue with USB.